# FOR EACH STATEMENT and FOR EACH ROW triggers order of execution

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

In a postgres database, say i have 3 tables, **tb1**, **tb2** and **tb3**.

**tb2** gets updated after insert on **tb1** for each row using trigger **T1**, and **tb3** gets updated after insert on **tb1** for each statement using trigger **T2**.

my situation is I don't want tb3 to get updated until tb1 and tb2 finish updating, because she uses both.

now if I execute a query that inserts 10k lines on tb1 after the last line is inserted in tb1 the statement will end. and trigger **T2** will fire. My question is, will **T2** fire before tb2 gets its last 10k-th line or after?

If before, can you propose a solution so that tb3 doesn't get updated until after the two tables get both all the inserts finished?

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY problem.

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right, but i also explained the situation, so if you have a completely different solution please share.

Comment: Can you add an actual example of what you are trying to achieve? FOR EACH raises the suspicion that you are doing things not the way they are meant to be done in a RDBMS.

Comment: The statement is not done until after the last row is inserted, so the `FOR STATMENT` will not fire until then. Set up a test and verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) has the desired information:

> Statement-level `BEFORE` triggers naturally fire before the statement starts to do anything, while statement-level `AFTER` triggers fire at the very end of the statement. These types of triggers may be defined on tables, views, or foreign tables. Row-level `BEFORE` triggers fire immediately before a particular row is operated on, while row-level `AFTER` triggers fire at the end of the statement (but before any statement-level `AFTER` triggers).
>
> [...]
>
> If more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name.

So you can rely on `t2` running after `t1`.